# Another problem with exception in tkinter callback

Tags: tkinter

I tried to create a window with a menu and i d'like to open a child window out of this menu. When I run the program the following exceptions appear:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in call return self.func(*args) 
File "\menu_child.py", line 19, in child_wnd win = Toplevel(self) 
File "\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2342, in init BaseWidget.init(self, master, 'toplevel', cnf, {}, extra) 
File \lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2292, in init BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf) 
File "\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 2269, in _setup if master._last_child_ids is None: 
AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute '_last_child_ids'
```

The Code looks like:

```
from tkinter import *


class MainWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()

        self.menu = Menu(self.tk)
        self.tk.config(menu=self.menu)

        self.main_menu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.main_menu.add_command(label="New Window", command=self.child_wnd)
        self.main_menu.add_command(label="Empty")
        self.main_menu.add_command(label="Useless")
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Main", menu=self.main_menu )


    def child_wnd(self):
        win = Toplevel(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':

main = MainWindow()
mainloop()
```

Could someone explain me whats going wrong? To be honestly i have no idea what to do. Thanks

Comment: Of course there is a hello missing. Got it in the text but it looks like i lost it somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `self` in `Toplevel(self)`. The first argument must be a widget, and `self` isn't a widget. In this specific case you can do `Toplevel(self.tk)`.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thank you for your help. It is working now. Seems like there is a lot more i have to learn.